# bluez4.101: headset disconnects immediately after connected

Tags: bluez, a2dp

I'm trying to make my PC(ubuntu14.04) work as a bluetooth headset, but each time after the phone connected the PC, it disconnects in few seconds.
Here is the hciconfig and hcidump, and bluez version is 4.101.
Do I miss something to keep the connection alive?

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1A:D5:50:00:BF  ACL MTU: 310:10  SCO MTU: 64:8
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:540 acl:0 sco:0 events:28 errors:0
    TX bytes:373 acl:0 sco:0 commands:28 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8f 0xfe 0x9b 0xf9 0x00 0x80
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'ubuntu-0'
    Class: 0x6c0100
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
    HCI Version: 2.0 (0x3)  Revision: 0xc5c
    LMP Version: 2.0 (0x3)  Subversion: 0xc5c
    Manufacturer: Cambridge Silicon Radio (10)

HCI sniffer - Bluetooth packet analyzer ver 2.5 device: hci0 snap_len: 1500 filter: 0xffffffffffffffff
> HCI Event: Connect Request (0x04) plen 10
    bdaddr 7C:7F:E8:35:55:76 class 0x5a020c type ACL
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Accept Connection Request (0x01|0x0009) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 10
    PIN Code Request Reply (0x01|0x000d) ncmd 1
    status 0x00 bdaddr 7C:7F:E8:35:55:76
> HCI Event: Connect Complete (0x03) plen 11
    status 0x00 handle 42 bdaddr 7C:7F:E8:35:55:76 type ACL encrypt 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Read Remote Supported Features (0x01|0x001b) status 0x00 ncmd 0
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Unknown (0x00|0x0000) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Read Remote Supported Features (0x0b) plen 11
    status 0x00 handle 42
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x8f 0xfe 0xd8 0x3f 0x5b 0x87
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Read Remote Extended Features (0x01|0x001c) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Read Remote Extended Features (0x23) plen 13
    status 0x00 handle 42 page 1 max 2
    Features: 0x0f 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Remote Name Request (0x01|0x0019) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Remote Name Req Complete (0x07) plen 255
    status 0x00 bdaddr 7C:7F:E8:35:55:76 name 'Phone'
> HCI Event: Encrypt Change (0x08) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 42 encrypt 0x01
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Exit Sniff Mode (0x02|0x0004) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Read Clock Offset (0x01|0x001f) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Read Clock Offset Complete (0x1c) plen 5
    status 0x13 handle 42 clkoffset 0x0000
    Error: Remote User Terminated Connection
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) status 0x00 ncmd 0
> HCI Event: Disconn Complete (0x05) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 42 reason 0x13
    Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection
> HCI Event: Disconn Complete (0x05) plen 4
    status 0x02 handle 42 reason 0x02
    Error: Unknown Connection Identifier
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Unknown (0x00|0x0000) status 0x00 ncmd 1
```

Comment: Share the logs of "systemctl --no-pager status bluetooth"

Comment: ubuntu:~$ systemctl --no-pager status bluetooth
systemctl: command not found
ubuntu:~$ systemctl
systemctl: command not found
ubuntu:~$ ps -aux | grep 'bluetoothd'
root       431  0.0  0.1  19428  3824 ?        Ss   13:52   0:00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd

Comment: Oops. Ubuntu 14.04 uses upstart. Am not sure about BlueZ4.x versions. It's outdated, I recommend you to upgrade to Bluez5

Comment: Thanks Parthiban, I upgrade to bluez5 and it works now.